# How do I confirm a form has been submitted with django?

Tags: python, django

I'm submitting a form and instead of redirecting to a success url I would like to just show "Form has been submitted" in text on the page when the form has been submitted. Does anyone know how I can do so?

Comment: What are you doing with regard to JavaScript? Are you using jQuery or any other framework?

Answer (score 4):

In your view:

```
if request.POST:
    # validate form, do what you need
    if form_is_valid():
        message = 'Form has been submitted'
        return render_to_response('path/to/template.html', {'message': message})
```

And then use code in your template like:

```
{% if message %}
    <h4>{{ message }}</h4>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This will still transition the page. Not sure that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Since he's making a POST request, the server will still need to send the browser a page.

Comment: No, that's not true when you use AJAX. Yes, it will need to send SOMETHING back, but using a normal form submission will blow the page away as part of that. Note the requirement that he wants the text to appear "on the page when the form has been submitted". AJAX is the way to go here.

Comment: Well, we won't know what he really wants until the OP picks an answer :)

Comment: I need to remain on the same page and just show the text "Form has been submitted." This method takes me to a new page.

Comment: @user995469 Then you need to use AJAX to POST the form.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this isn't a Django-specific issue. The problem is whether you are doing a normal form submission or using AJAX.

The basic idea is to POST to your form submission endpoint using AJAX and the form data, and in the Django view, merely update your models and return either an empty 200 response or some data (in XML, JSON, small HTML, whatever you need). Then the AJAX call can populate a success message `div` on success, or display a failure message if it gets back a non-200 response.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your view to return an HttpResponse object with the text you want as its parameter, after you have validated the request.  See the example below.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            return HttpResponse('Form has been submitted.')
```